# Validation for two select boxes

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys, i need a javascript coding for two select drop-down boxes, both are language drop downs.
The validation function which i need with conditions is

1. both boxes should not be in the default `select` option,
2. both boxes should not hold same values
3. User cannot add second language without adding first language (i have this code already, please see the code below)

The html code:

```
<select name="language1">
  <option value='Select' selected="selected">Select </option>
  <option value='Bengali'>Bengali </option>
  <option value='Gujarati'>Gujarati </option>
  <option value='Hindi'>Hindi </option>
</select>

<select name="language2">
  <option value='Select' selected="selected">Select </option>
  <option value='Bengali'>Bengali </option>
  <option value='Gujarati'>Gujarati </option>
  <option value='Hindi'>Hindi </option>
</select>
```

This javascript is what i have added:

```
/* if regional language 2 filled without filling language1 then raise an error... */
if (document.f_edit_shop.language1.value) { }
else { 
  if (document.f_edit_shop.language2.value) { 
    document.getElementById("validationMessage").innerHTML=
      "&nbsp;<font color='#FF0000'>Error: </font> You can not select Language 2 
      without selecting Language 1 !";
    popup('validationPopup');
    language2.focus();
    return false;
  } 
}
```

I need this script also with it. . .

Answer (score 1):

```
var lng1 = document.f_edit_shop.language1;
var lng2 = document.f_edit_shop.language2;
var errBox = document.getElementById("validationMessage");

function validate() {
  errBox.innerHTML = '';

  if (lng1.selectedIndex !== 0 || lng2.selectedIndex !== 0)
    errBox.innerHTML += 'Select an option for both boxes<br>';

  if (lng1.selectedIndex === 0 && lng2.selectedIndex !== 0)
    errBox.innerHTML += 'Select a language for first box<br>';

  if (lng1.selectedIndex === lng2.selectedIndex)
    errBox.innerHTML += 'You can\'t select same language twice<br>';
}
```